# Extract Table Information from HTML (As Text File)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to extract information from a table in an html file, I want to use this possible as a text as I can only access this file through VPN so I have downloaded all the necessary html files I need.

I want to specifically get the information from various tables of the same table class, however when I try to obtain the information there is nothing being returned. I have attached the code that I was trying to use to obtain this information but have not been successful.

Below also is the html file that I have been trying to get the information from, it is quite big however so I hope this to not be a problem

[Table Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlOpP.png)

```html
<table class="region-table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Region</th>
   <th>Type</th>
   <th>From</th>
   <th>To</th>
   <th colspan="2">Most similar known cluster</th>
   <th>Similarity</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr class="linked-row odd" data-anchor="#r1c1">
     
     
     <td class="regbutton NRPS-like r1c1">
      <a href="#r1c1">Region&nbsp;1.1</a>
     </td>
     <td>
       
       <a class="external-link" href="https://docs.antismash.secondarymetabolites.org/glossary/#nrps-like" target="_blank">NRPS-like</a>
     </td>
     <td class="digits">21,469</td>
     <td class="digits table-split-left">62,957</td>
     
      
        
      
      <td><a class="external-link" href="https://mibig.secondarymetabolites.org/go/BGC0001740/1" target="_blank">phthoxazolin</a></td>
      <td>NRP + Polyketide</td>
      <td class="digits similarity-text" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3), rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3) 4%, #ffffff00 4%)">4%</td>
     
   </tr>
 <tr class="linked-row even" data-anchor="#r1c2">
     
     
     <td class="regbutton NRPS r1c2">
      <a href="#r1c2">Region&nbsp;1.2</a>
     </td>
     <td>
       
       <a class="external-link" href="https://docs.antismash.secondarymetabolites.org/glossary/#nrps" target="_blank">NRPS</a>
     </td>
     <td class="digits">74,163</td>
     <td class="digits table-split-left">124,963</td>
     
      
        
      
      <td><a class="external-link" href="https://mibig.secondarymetabolites.org/go/BGC0001709/1" target="_blank">nystatin</a></td>
      <td>Polyketide</td>
      <td class="digits similarity-text" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3), rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3) 10%, #ffffff00 10%)">10%</td>
     
   </tr>
 
 </tbody>
</table>
<table class="region-table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Region</th>
   <th>Type</th>
   <th>From</th>
   <th>To</th>
   <th colspan="2">Most similar known cluster</th>
   <th>Similarity</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr class="linked-row odd" data-anchor="#r2c1">
     
     
     <td class="regbutton terpene r2c1">
      <a href="#r2c1">Region&nbsp;2.1</a>
     </td>
     <td>
       
       <a class="external-link" href="https://docs.antismash.secondarymetabolites.org/glossary/#terpene" target="_blank">terpene</a>
     </td>
     <td class="digits">3,800</td>
     <td class="digits table-split-left">23,263</td>
     
      
        
      
      <td><a class="external-link" href="https://mibig.secondarymetabolites.org/go/BGC0001580/1" target="_blank">ebelactone</a></td>
      <td>Polyketide</td>
      <td class="digits similarity-text" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3), rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3) 5%, #ffffff00 5%)">5%</td>
     
   </tr>
 <tr class="linked-row even" data-anchor="#r2c2">
     
     
     <td class="regbutton NRPS-like r2c2">
      <a href="#r2c2">Region&nbsp;2.2</a>
     </td>
     <td>
       
       <a class="external-link" href="https://docs.antismash.secondarymetabolites.org/glossary/#nrps-like" target="_blank">NRPS-like</a>
     </td>
     <td class="digits">55,320</td>
     <td class="digits table-split-left">97,088</td>
     
      
        
      
      <td><a class="external-link" href="https://mibig.secondarymetabolites.org/go/BGC0000727/1" target="_blank">indigoidine</a></td>
      <td>Saccharide</td>
      <td class="digits similarity-text" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3), rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3) 17%, #ffffff00 17%)">17%</td>
     
   </tr>
 <tr class="linked-row odd" data-anchor="#r2c3">
     
     
     <td class="regbutton NRPS r2c3">
      <a href="#r2c3">Region&nbsp;2.3</a>
     </td>
     <td>
       
       <a class="external-link" href="https://docs.antismash.secondarymetabolites.org/glossary/#nrps" target="_blank">NRPS</a>
     </td>
     <td class="digits">144,740</td>
     <td class="digits table-split-left">193,599</td>
     
      
        
      
      <td><a class="external-link" href="https://mibig.secondarymetabolites.org/go/BGC0000368/1" target="_blank">streptobactin</a></td>
      <td>NRP</td>
      <td class="digits similarity-text" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(210, 105, 30, 0.3), rgba(210, 105, 30, 0.3) 70%, #ffffff00 70%)">70%</td>
     
   </tr>
 <tr class="linked-row even" data-anchor="#r2c4">
     
     
     <td class="regbutton siderophore r2c4">
      <a href="#r2c4">Region&nbsp;2.4</a>
     </td>
     <td>
       
       <a class="external-link" href="https://docs.antismash.secondarymetabolites.org/glossary/#siderophore" target="_blank">siderophore</a>
     </td>
     <td class="digits">347,862</td>
     <td class="digits table-split-left">362,833</td>
     
      
        
      
      <td><a class="external-link" href="https://mibig.secondarymetabolites.org/go/BGC0001593/1" target="_blank">ficellomycin</a></td>
      <td>NRP</td>
      <td class="digits similarity-text" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3), rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3) 3%, #ffffff00 3%)">3%</td>
     
   </tr>
 <tr class="linked-row odd" data-anchor="#r2c5">
     
     
     <td class="regbutton lassopeptide r2c5">
      <a href="#r2c5">Region&nbsp;2.5</a>
     </td>
     <td>
       
       <a class="external-link" href="https://docs.antismash.secondarymetabolites.org/glossary/#lassopeptide" target="_blank">lassopeptide</a>
     </td>
     <td class="digits">548,017</td>
     <td class="digits table-split-left">570,561</td>
     
      
        
      
      <td><a class="external-link" href="https://mibig.secondarymetabolites.org/go/BGC0001435/1" target="_blank">ikarugamycin</a></td>
      <td>NRP + Polyketide:Iterative type I</td>
      <td class="digits similarity-text" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3), rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3) 12%, #ffffff00 12%)">12%</td>
     
   </tr>
 <tr class="linked-row even" data-anchor="#r2c6">
     
     
     <td class="regbutton NRPS r2c6">
      <a href="#r2c6">Region&nbsp;2.6</a>
     </td>
     <td>
       
       <a class="external-link" href="https://docs.antismash.secondarymetabolites.org/glossary/#nrps" target="_blank">NRPS</a>
     </td>
     <td class="digits">628,834</td>
     <td class="digits table-split-left">683,050</td>
     
      
        
      
      <td><a class="external-link" href="https://mibig.secondarymetabolites.org/go/BGC0001117/1" target="_blank">himastatin</a></td>
      <td>NRP</td>
      <td class="digits similarity-text" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3), rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3) 12%, #ffffff00 12%)">12%</td>
     
   </tr>
 <tr class="linked-row odd" data-anchor="#r2c7">
     
     
         
     
     <td class="regbutton NRPS,terpene hybrid r2c7">
      <a href="#r2c7">Region&nbsp;2.7</a>
     </td>
     <td>
       
       <a class="external-link" href="https://docs.antismash.secondarymetabolites.org/glossary/#nrps" target="_blank">NRPS</a>,<a class="external-link" href="https://docs.antismash.secondarymetabolites.org/glossary/#terpene" target="_blank">terpene</a>
     </td>
     <td class="digits">1,043,511</td>
     <td class="digits table-split-left">1,104,786</td>
     
      
        
      
      <td><a class="external-link" href="https://mibig.secondarymetabolites.org/go/BGC0002024/1" target="_blank">nargenicin</a></td>
      <td>Polyketide</td>
      <td class="digits similarity-text" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3), rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.3) 11%, #ffffff00 11%)">11%</td>
     
   </tr>
 
 </tbody>
</table>
```

## Code Snippet

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
gdp_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "region-table"})
gdp_table_data = gdp_table.tbody.find_all("tr")  # contains 2 rows
# Get all the headings of Lists
print ("Extracted {num} Region-Tables".format(num=len(gdp_table_data)))
print(gdp_table_data[0]) #print first table
print(gdp_table_data[1]) #print second table
```

**Ideally I would want to input the html file and extract all the different tables information, merge as one big table and output as csv possibly.**

Comment: You probably don't need beautifulsoup for this. Try using pandas' `read_html()` method.

Comment: That code does not print anything/return anything?

Comment: @AMC - It did in my case; something like `tbl="""[op's html]""" print(pd.read_html(tbl))` printed the target table.

Comment: @JackFleeting Sorry if my comment wasn't clear, I was asking for clarification regarding what OP wrote: _when I try to obtain the information there is nothing being returned._

Comment: @JackFleeting  this was quite a useful tool, I have been trying to use the BeautifulSoup module but has been giving quite some trouble in general However, when I use this method it repeats the last table once again.

Comment: What do you mean by "it repeats the last table once again"?

Comment: @JackFleeting there was an issue with my html link apparently and copies each one twice, so just by splicing at the end, it was possible `table = table[:-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take HTML data from the file and export a separate csv.

```
import csv
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
name = 'test.html'
html = utils.getFileContent(name) # Get data from file
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
rows = []
tables = doc.selects('table.region-table')
for table in tables:
    trs = table.tbody.trs
    for tr in trs:
        rows.append([td.text for td in tr.tds])
with open(name+'.csv','w',encoding='utf-8') as f: 
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerows(rows)
```

If you want to keep one file per table

```
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
i=0
tables = doc.selects('table.region-table')
for table in tables:
    i+=1
    rows = []
    trs = table.tbody.trs
    for tr in trs:
        rows.append([td.text for td in tr.tds])
    with open(name+str(i)+'.csv','w',encoding='utf-8') as f: 
        csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
        csv_writer.writerows(rows)
```

Keep the original one for comparison.

```
import csv
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req
html = '''''' # Your HTML
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
rows = []
tables = doc.selects('table.region-table')
for table in tables:
    trs = table.tbody.trs
    for tr in trs:
        rows.append([td.text for td in tr.tds])
 # If you have '>Region.*?</a>' in each row, you can get all the rows directly in the following way
 # trs = doc.getElementsByReg('>Region.*?</a>',tag='tr')
 # for tr in trs:
    # rows.append([td.text for td in tr.tds])
with open('test.csv','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerows(rows)
```

Result:

```
Region 1.1,NRPS-like,"21,469","62,957",phthoxazolin,NRP + Polyketide,4%
Region 1.2,NRPS,"74,163","124,963",nystatin,Polyketide,10%
Region 2.1,terpene,"3,800","23,263",ebelactone,Polyketide,5%
Region 2.2,NRPS-like,"55,320","97,088",indigoidine,Saccharide,17%
Region 2.3,NRPS,"144,740","193,599",streptobactin,NRP,70%
Region 2.4,siderophore,"347,862","362,833",ficellomycin,NRP,3%
Region 2.5,lassopeptide,"548,017","570,561",ikarugamycin,NRP + Polyketide:Iterative type I,12%
Region 2.6,NRPS,"628,834","683,050",himastatin,NRP,12%
Region 2.7,"NRPS,terpene","1,043,511","1,104,786",nargenicin,Polyketide,11%
```

Comment: hey @dabingou, interesting approach to handle this. I unfortunately continue to get an error  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplified_scrapy'` and I can't find the function SimplifiedDoc() as well unfortunately to be working..

Comment: @Biohacker Sorry, I forgot to say. This is a third party lib. Need to be installed like BeautifulSoup. pip install simplified_scrapy

Comment: thanks so much! This is working perfectly, I have a separate question. Is it possible to input a .html file to be read as text where `html = ''''HTML TEXT HERE''` for example? As I want to loop through a directory that has various html files and export a separate csv for each

Comment: @Biohacker Sure. Wait a minute. I'll change the code for you.

Comment: you are definitely the best! :) I made a small adaptation to work with the data as pandas dataframes for manipulating a bit easier but you helped so much! :) I think like this I can loop through all my index.html files and create the respective seperate csv files

Comment: Thanks for the update, this is quite useful to view each table seperately, however as I mentioned it would hopefully be 1 csv file per each html file saved in each subdirectory when executing the python script. Thanks once again.